# OrderBy según una relación de muchos a muchos laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

tengo este query

```
    return Franchise::with(['customers' => function ($query) use ($formulaToGetNearestLocation){
        $query->select(DB::raw($formulaToGetNearestLocation))
            ->orderBy('distance', 'asc');
    }])->paginate(10);
```

en la relación se está ordenando como quiero a través de "distancias", sin embargo lo está haciendo en la misma relación, quiero que ese orden afecte al query final, es decir, quiero que esas Franchises estén ordenadas según la distancia de los customers

**nota:** la relación es muchos a muchos.
**nota 2:** algunas Franchises no están relacionadas a ningún Customer en la tabla intermedia, si es posible, quisiera que estos resultados se muestren al inicio de todo

es posible hacer un query asi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no conozco que versión concreta de Laravel estás utilizando, pero puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
return Franchise::with(['customers' => function ($query) use ($formulaToGetNearestLocation){
    $query->select(DB::raw($formulaToGetNearestLocation));
}])->orderByRaw('-`distance` ASC')->paginate(10);
```

En vez de hacer el ***orderBy*** en el query relacional, lo haces al final.

Te he comentado lo de la versión de laravel porque a partir de la 5.4 puedes utilizar ***orderByRaw***, que se introdujo para ello, en cuanto al funcionamiento, ***-`distance*** hace referencia al campo en el que quieres basarte para el orden, y el ***-*** de delante declara que también reciba aquellos que tienen el campo ***distance*** a *NULL* como su valor.

Si te he entendido bien, hay Customers que su campo ***distance*** tiene un valor nulo al no existir la relación con ninguna Franchise y querías que la query ordenase los resultados a partir de este campo.

Comment: perdón por dejar pasar el dato, es laravel 8

Comment: Sin problema, me imaginaba que sería una versión superior pero me gusta concretar, espero que te haya sido de ayuda ;) @AndréCuellarAvaroma

Comment: gracias, me ha funcionado en uno, pero tengo otro en el que el mismo campo "distance" no es un campo de la base de datos existente, si no que viene de toda una formula y al final el resultado es. AS distance, con ese cómo podría hacerlo?ç

Comment: Si te estoy entendiendo, hay un customer que te ha funcionado porque en la base de datos tiene el campo distance, pero en otro no te funciona porque no tiene ese atributo estoy en lo cierto?

Comment: asi es, distance es sacado de DB::raw(.... AS distance)

Comment: Ya he entendido, en este caso concreto la verdad es que me pillas ya que hace bastante que no trabajo con Laravel y no recuerdo que se me haya dado este caso, la cosa es que los parámetros que declaras en una query mediante AS, creo que solo se pueden leer desde esa misma query. Entonces, en está situación solo podrías utilizar el valor generado por AS en la query del select(DB::raw), pero no fuera de ella como hacemos con el distance que si procede de la base de datos. No se si se me ha entendido, pero en este caso concreto no podemos aplicar esa lógica con el valor resultante del AS.

Comment: gracias, creo que eso será un tema para después